# Sengled lights keep resetting and disconnecting from network

Tags: google-home, samsung-smartthings, smart-lights

I have 12 sengled RGB lights throughout my home. I have had them hooked up and working great for nearly 2 years, but lately seemingly random, I'll see one of the lights reset as if it was the first time turning it on. At that point, I can no longer control it.

When I go to re-add them to the network, the Smart Things app will automatically bring the device back into the network without me having to manually select it. This process will then repeat every few days.

This started with 1 of my lights and then slowly over the next 2 weeks, almost like some sort of pathogen, each light started doing the same thing. Now all my lights disconnect and I have to go to Smartthings to let it know that there is an issue.

**EDIT**
After looking through some debug logs with Smartthings IDE, I discovered that the devices were not allowed to rejoin insecure zigbee network. I have never changed this setting in the past but now all of a sudden I am having these issues.

A potential solution is to disable this security feature and allow the devices to connect to insecure region. Since my zigbee network only includes LED lights, I dont see an issue with this, but I am not a security expert.

But it makes me nervous since I have never had this issue in the past.

**A few things that may be important to this situation:**

1. I live in a high rise apartment complex where there are many networks around me
2. I have all my smart devices on my primary network, not the guest network.
3. I am using the default network settings provided by the ATT router when I signed up for the service
4. All the lights are on analog dimmer circuits, but I leave the brightness at 100% at all times.
5. All my other smart devices have not had any issues.
6. I use Google Home as my smart assistant
7. All devices connect to smartthings hub which connects to the router.
8. All devices run on Zigbee

**My questions are this:**

1. Why would this just now occur after all this time?
2. How do I stop this from continuing to occur?

Comment: maybe the lights are doing a firmware update

Comment: Have you tried assigning static IP addresses to them ?

Comment: I have added 2 additional items to my list of known environment conditions.